# Replace element in matrix in row with 1 and 0 matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, replace, compare, row

I have an n x n matrix in MATLAB. In every row, if the value in each element is higher than a certain threshold, replace that element with a 1. Else, with a 0.
**NOTICE**: In every row, we compare the value of element with different threshold.

Answer (score 1):

For element-wise comparison of two matrices of the same size, use the "`>`" operator e.g. `result = data > threshold` (this will return ones and zeroes depending on whether the condition is satisfied or not).

Suppose you have your data in a matrix called `data` and your thresholds in a column vector called `thresholds` (i.e. `length(thresholds) == size(data, 1)`). You can create an array the same size as the data matrix using `repmat`: `thresholdsMatrix = repmat(thresholds, 1, size(data, 2))`.
You can then compare this to your data:

`result = data > repmat(thresholds, 1, size(data, 2))`.
This should give you the result you want.

[Note that you can also directly compare the vector to the matrix without using `repmat` i.e. `result = data > thresholds`, but IMO this can be unclear and may lead to unexpected behaviour]